# Graph theory, finding the degree of a vertex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Ok so that is the graph. I am trying to find the degrees of the vertex. My book said that the degree of vertice D is 4, but I am not seeing how that is possible. I know the degree is the number of edges of which a vertice lies on, but I can only see two. What am I missing?

Comment: If the picture is correct, you’re not missing a thing: the degree of $D$ *is* $2$. The degrees of $A$ and $E$ are also $2$, the degree of $C$ is $1$, and the degree of $B$ is $3$. Note that these numbers sum to $10$, twice the number of edges, just as they should.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: How is the degree of A 2? AB, AC, and AE are 3 edges?

Comment: $AC$ isn't an edge. There is a *path* from $A$ to $C$, via edges $AB$ and $BC$.

Comment: What...the hell is my professor teaching

Answer (score 1):

The only way $deg(D)=4$ is if $D$ has a loop, a loop i counting twice

Answer (score 0):

I too think deg(D)=2. There are only two edges that have D as an endpoint.